# Unity ADS - 'Advertisment' does not contain definition for 'AddListener'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play, ads, unityads

I am trying to add reward-able ads to my plat-former app but it does not let me add a listener as stated in the documentation. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Show the script part.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a simple spelling error, change AddListener to AdListener and it should fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be an outdated version of Advertisement Package. In Unity, open Window > Package Manager and update the Advertisement package to the latest version, I used 3.4.2.

Check this thread here for more details: https://forum.unity.com/threads/iunityadslistener-not-found.712283/